# Configuration Management for Installation of OS

Tags: configuration-management

I was looking for a uniform configuration management tool for remote installation of OS on remote servers(similar to puppet/chef) having wide range of platform support. I think we can use PXE/kickstart for remote installation. I am not sure that can be used to install OS on multiple servers in parallel?  Other way to spin up the EC2 instance from AWS and pay amazon for the usage. I was wondering is there any other best option for this requirement?

Regards
Bubunia

Answer (score 0):

You can consider ansible as a strong candidate for this.

Some of its features:

1. Open source with large development community
2. Number of modules which can help you building flexible solutions.
3. Cloud focused development modules
4. Ansible inventory which can help you automate things end to end on the basis of tags to your instances
5. Agent less
6. Easy to write, read and understand yaml format
7. Pre-builded modules for multiple installations available in open source community
8. Work with multiple OS

It is efficient as well I am using it from last 1 year and found it very good.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Can ansible be used to install OS to remote servers for example Out of 15 servers I want to install CentOS in first 5 servers and want to install Ubuntu in next 5 servers and want to install Windows in next 5 servers. Is it Possible? If so could you please provide me the code snippet(yaml file) for this scenarios?

Comment: Ansible will not be able to install OS it can do configuration after OS installation. For OS installation you have to use amazon AMI configuration.

Answer (score 0):

[Sparrow6](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrow6/blob/master/documentation/dsl.md#helper-functions) cm supports quite a range of platforms/os. You can choose [Sparrowdo](https://github.com/melezhik/Sparrowdo) to run configuration jobs in push manner over ssh.